# CSS - div always absolute middle left of screen even if page scroll

Tags: html, css

I want display a timer always absolute middle left of screen **even if page scroll**. (is it img on my draw)

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                             | |
|   ^                                                         | |
|  50%                  line 1                                | |
|                                                             | |
|                       line 2                                | |
|-----+                                                       | |
| img |                 line 3                                | |
|-----+                                                       | |
|                       line 4                                | |
|                                                             | |
|                       line 5                                | |
|  50%                                                        | |
|                       line 6                                | |
|                                                             |>|
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
                        line 7

                        line 8
```

after scroll:

```
                        line 1
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                       line 2                                | |
|   ^                                                         | |
|  50%                  line 3                                | |
|                                                             | |
|                       line 4                                | |
|-----+                                                       | |
| img |                 line 5                                | |
|-----+                                                       | |
|                       line 6                                | |
|                                                             | |
|                       line 7                                | |
|  50%                                                        | |
|                       line 8                                | |
|                                                             |>|
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I try:

```
<div class="timer">
  <p>img</p>
</div>

.timer {
  /* ... */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Rojo, read the end of post please before write a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.timer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```

An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used to position the element.

your idea is correct if needed you can try out all possible values to figure out which gives you the result.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: `top: 50%` places the element below the middle, you can center it by adding `transform: translateY(-50%);`

Comment: @metatron, `transform: translateY(-50%)` do not work

Comment: you should use it in addition to the answer, so `position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 0; transform: translateY(-50%)`

Comment: @metatron, YES, good work, I edit this response with your Suestion. thank you

Comment: There's 2 times 50% in the css code but these boil down to different values. In case you're wondering why this code works I'll elaborate a bit: when using percentages in top/right/bottom/left values these values are **a percentage of the dimensions of the positioning context** (in case of position fixed the positioning context is the viewport). When using percentages in a transform rule the values are **a percentage of the elements own dimensions**. So in human language this code states: place the top of the element 50% from the top of the viewport and move it half of its height up.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use `position: fixed` for that.

Here's an example on how you would implement it:

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fixed-position {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  top: 50%;  /* Move div 50% top of screen */
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -20px; /* margin-top should be negative half of element's height to center div on the screen */
  position: fixed;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixed-position"></div>

  <main class="content">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    
    <h5>What is lorem ipsum?</h5>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    
    <h5>Where does it come from?</h5>
    <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>

    <h5>Why do we use it?</h5>
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    
    <h5>Where can I get some?</h5>
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
  </main>
</div>
```